# ASP.NET MVC DropDownLists

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to give the please select item a value of 0 or -1?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you want exactly ?

Answer (score 1):

Supposing *Model.Services* contains list of *ServiceType* objects you could add an item to the list like this:

```
<%= 
    Html.DropDownList("ServiceId", new SelectList(
        new [] 
        {
            new ServiceType 
            {
                Id = 0,
                Name = "-- Please Select --"
            }
        }.Union(Model.Services), "Id", "Name"), 0)
%>
```